# Accepting Multiple Clients in Java TCP and make each client wait for 5 minutes

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, connection, udp

i am trying to make a  TCP server In java that accepts 10 clients, each client should be treated on thread so no clients are waiting. Each thread will receive the client and make him wait for 5 minutes.

here's my so far code;

public class ThreadServer {

```
static class ServerThread implements Runnable {
Socket client = null;
public ServerThread(Socket c) {
    this.client = c;
}
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Connected to client : "+client.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        client.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8787);
        while (true) {
            Socket p = server.accept();
            new Thread(new ServerThread(p)).start();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Error : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Okay? Doesn't sound very useful, but it's your server. So what are you having problems with? Don't know how to use Thread.sleep()?

Comment: how to put each client accepted on wait for 5 minutes

Comment: So you know about socket connections, but not about Thread.sleep()?

Comment: Well, I guess it's time for you to learn about `Thread.sleep()` then.

Comment: Like @Kayaman says, one of the easiest and weirdest reqirements ever.  sleep(5*60*1000) at top of server<>client thread.

Comment: “each client should be treated on thread **so no clients are waiting**. Each thread will receive the client and make him **wait for 5 minutes**” So your clients shall not wait to wait?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved easily with a ScheduledExecutorService like this:

```
public class RespondLater implements Runnable {

  final Socket client;

  public RespondLater(final Socket c) {
    this.client = c;
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      System.out.println("5 minutes later on client: " + client.getInetAddress().getHostName());
      // do whatever you want with the client 5 minutes later here
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
      try {
        client.close();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    try (final ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8787)) {
      while (true) {
        final Socket p = server.accept();
        executor.schedule(new RespondLater(p), 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.err.println("Error : " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
      executor.shutdownNow();
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that there are never more than `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` threads active, so you can have this construct handle probably thousands of connections.

I assume however that most clients will time-out before the 5 minute mark is reached.

Comment: The user didn’t ask for thousands of connections. The question says “10 clients”.

Comment: Nobody forces you to use more than 10.

Comment: Well, it looked like a precise requirement to me to allow exactly ten clients. Praying that the rest of the internet won’t connect on that server doesn’t sound like a solution to me. However, I don’t know whether it really is a requirement. That’s hard to predict on such weird question.

Comment: There is the possibility to check the current queue size of the executor or have an AtomicInteger as counter for a more precise counting, however as you said: the question is not precise enough figure out what the correct answer would be.